# How do I restart a python script running inside of a screen using a bash script?

Tags: python, linux, git, bash, shell

Okay here's my situation:

On a server I have a screen session (which was initiated using `screen -S python-script`) running a python script inside of it.

I make changes to this project by pushing to a git repo. When I want to have the changes reflected on the project, I ssh into the server, `screen -x python-script` and then Ctrl-c to send keyboard interrupt, then `git pull origin master` and then `./run_script.py`

I want to do something clever and make my project able to update and restart itself. Another small python server would live on this remote server and listen for a request from my project, this python server would then use `subprocess` to run a bash script which would update and restart my project.

It's a bit convoluted I know, and I'd really like some suggestions if there's a better way to do what I'm wanting.

Right now if I could formulate a bash script to do what I'm looking for, then I know this would work (probably..).

Comment: You can use `pkill` to kill the running script and kill the screen. From then on you can start the script via screen, `screen -S python-script bash -c "git pull origin master; ./run_script.py"`. Everytime you kill `run_script.py` the screen wil automatically terminate as well.

Comment: Unfortunately there's some serious environment configuration going on inside the screen. Maintaining the screen session is pretty much essential. Also I need to be sure to send a keyboard interrupt because the framework I use is threaded and it recognizes keyboard interrupts to safely shut things down.

Comment: What's stopping you from writing an environment file that can be sourced? Sending `SIGINT` to the process is equivalent to pressing `Ctrl+C`. What's stopping you from sending this signal to your process? If none of these can be done, then you are better off with your current manual process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Use [nohup](http://linux.die.net/man/1/nohup) instead of screen, redirect stdout to a rotative log if you're interested  in the outputs. Store the PID somewhere.

2) Set a 'deployment' branch on your repo.

3) Set a [cronjob](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) on the server to  pull 'deployment' branch each x minutes.

4) Use a [githook](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks) to trigger an start/stop each time there's a new commit on your 'deployment' branch. Use the stored pid to kill it.

---

EDIT:

If you need to kill via Ctrl + C, just send [SIGINT](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) with kill then [wait](http://ss64.com/bash/wait.html) for the pid to die.